# tess4j not working on web application with 64 bit JDK

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, ocr, tesseract, tess4j

![java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI1.TessBaseAPIGetUTF8Text(Native Method)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract1.getOCRText(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract1.doOCR(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract1.doOCR(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract1.doOCR(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract1.doOCR(Unknown Source)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiMyZ.png)

Answer (score 2):

That error is usually attributed to Tesseract not finding its `tessdata` folder. Try to point to it using `setDatapath` method.

Comment: It worked , Thank you nguyenq for your quick response.